# Are there different types of queries?

Tags: database

Linear queries (or linear aggregation queries) are of the form q=(q1,q2...) , where q is a real values vector and one gets the results of the query on a value 'x' by the process of a vector product as qx = q1x1+q2x2+... 
Are there any other types of queries that can be classified like this?